# Reading .hex File with C# File.ReadAllBytes()

Tags: c#, hex, hex-file

Im Working on a Program that Write One Page on MCUs . I Managed to Transfer one Page (128 byte) with fixed values (0x11) to MCU . now i want to read *.hex file and copy its content to byte[128] and then transfer it . but Problem is , Value that Progsip is showing in Buffer is Different with Values that i read from File .

Real Values that i expect to read :

[image]

Values with c# (File.ReadAllBytes()):

[image]

if you open hex file with Progisp , Buffer Page will Show you First Picture . Now open file with NotePad++ and Convert All of it to Hex (ASCI -> Hex) with Hex Plugin . it shows Second Picture That is the same with C# File.ReadAllBytes(). what makes Difference between Two Softwares ? (NotePad++ & Progisp)

[Hex File Link](https://ir11.uploadboy.com/d/gsy8z63spqwe/ubngc5okjdonbl6hr4uwtxoiwsrcf4bplp2araxlbnvjoguxvhc2o4b2bwwjimdomgbhpfhj/Usart_LCD.hex?cdn=1223959)

I opened file with NotePad++ and here it is :

```
:100000000C942A000C9447000C9447000C94470071
:100010000C9447000C9447000C9447000C94470044
:100020000C9447000C9447000C9447000C94470034
:100030000C9447000C9471010C9447000C944700F9
:100040000C9447000C9447000C9447000C94470014
:100050000C94470011241FBECFE5D8E0DEBFCDBF12
:1000600010E0A0E6B0E0EEEAF3E002C005900D92E9
:10007000A03AB107D9F720E0A0EAB0E001C01D9294
:10008000A23AB207E1F70E949A010C94D5010C94B0
:100090000000009751F0019779F488B3816088BB24
:1000A00082E08A95F1F700C0089588B38E7F88BBFF
:1000B00082E08A95F1F700C00895009751F001970A
:1000C00079F488B3826088BB82E08A95F1F700C03A
:1000D000089588B38D7F88BB82E08A95F1F700C0D0
:1000E0000895009751F0019779F488B3846088BB34
:1000F00082E08A95F1F700C0089588B38B7F88BBB2
:1001000082E08A95F1F700C00895CF93C82F8FEF52
:100110008ABB6115710521F06130710531F009C0AC
:1001200080E090E00E94490004C081E090E00E94DD
:10013000490080E090E00E945D0081E090E00E9434
:10014000710082E08A95F1F700C0CBBB80E090E0BF
:100150000E9471008FEC97E00197F1F700C000005A
:1001600081E090E00E94710092E09A95F1F700C062
:10017000CF910895CF93E091A100E034A1F0C82F72
:10018000F0E0E05AFF4F808160E070E080580E940C
:10019000850061E070E08C2F0E9485008091A100B5
:1001A0008F5F8093A100CF910895CF93803108F0A5
:1001B00045C0643008F042C0C82F61110DC0E82F5F
:1001C000F0E0E05AFF4F808160E070E080580E94CC
:1001D0008500C093A10032C0613079F4E82FF0E0CF
:1001E000E059FF4F808160E070E080580E948500F8
:1001F00080E18C0F8093A10021C0623079F4E82F58
:10020000F0E0E058FF4F808160E070E080580E948D
:10021000850080E28C0F8093A10010C0633071F4E0
:10022000E82FF0E0E057FF4F808160E070E08058F9
:100230000E94850080E38C0F8093A100CF910895E8
:10024000009741F0019759F460E070E08CE00E9463
:100250008500089560E070E088E00E9485000895C0
:1002600060E070E081E00E9485008FE99FE00197E7
:10027000F1F700C000001092A10008952FEF80E771
:1002800092E0215080409040E1F700C0000087B329
:10029000876087BB60E070E088E30E94850081E0B2
:1002A00090E00E9420010E94300160E070E086E052
:1002B0000E9485001092A10008958BB18BB98AB17C
:1002C000886D8AB980B58E6A80BD10BC83E389B918
:1002D00008955D9BFECF8CB908955F9BFECF8CB1D6
:1002E00008951F920F920FB60F9211242F933F93F0
:1002F0004F935F936F937F938F939F93AF93BF932E
:10030000EF93FF93F8948CB18093A0000E94BA0001
:100310007894FF91EF91BF91AF919F918F917F91D1
:100320006F915F914F913F912F910F900FBE0F9062
:100330001F901895CF930E945D010E943E0160E0DE
:1003400087E00E94D50087B3886087BB88B3886048
:1003500088BB2FEF89E698E1215080409040E1F77B
:1003600000C000008FE40E94BA008EE40E94BA0030
:100370000E946D018093A000C0E005C08091A000A4
:100380000E946901CF5FCA30C8F32FEF8DE399E473
:10039000215080409040E1F700C0000088B3877F83
:0E03A00088BB80E090E0CF910895F894FFCFE5
:1003AE00000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0FC7
:1003BE00404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4FB7
:1003CE00101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1FA7
:1003DE00505152535455565758595A5B5C5D5E5F97
:00000001FF
```

Comment: What's the question? Post any code, expected and actual data as text. Images can't be compiled and tested. `File.ReadAllBytes` works. The extension `.hex` doesn't change how data is read from disk.

Comment: *"Real Values that i expect to read"* - How did you read those values?

Comment: What do you see when you open that file in Notepad, binary "rubbish" or hex digits? If hex, then you shouldn't read it as bytes, but text and convert afterwards

Comment: A [mcve] showing the code you have written that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help.  See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for including the text contents of your file.  That looks like an [Intel HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) file, so I added the appropriate tags.  I think you're going to need to look through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) for the file format description.  An Intel HEX file isn't just a stream of bytes, it's broken down into records that have byte counts, addresses, record types and data.  You will need to write a parser/deserializer to process such a file.  Good luck!

Comment: See also [Convert hex to bin file with correct address offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41446654/3744182) whose answer describes the file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Searched in web and find out what problem is . so i write a HexToBin Function to do the things :

```
public byte AsciiToByte(byte ch)
    {
        byte ret = 0;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 48:
                ret = 0;
                break;
            case 49:
                ret = 1;
                break;
            case 50:
                ret = 2;
                break;
            case 51:
                ret = 3;
                break;
            case 52:
                ret = 4;
                break;
            case 53:
                ret = 5;
                break;
            case 54:
                ret = 6;
                break;
            case 55:
                ret = 7;
                break;
            case 56:
                ret = 8;
                break;
            case 57:
                ret = 9;
                break;
            case 65:
                ret = 10;
                break;
            case 66:
                ret = 11;
                break;
            case 67:
                ret = 12;
                break;
            case 68:
                ret = 13;
                break;
            case 69:
                ret = 14;
                break;
            case 70:
                ret = 15;
                break;
        }
        return ret;
    }



    public int HexToByteArray(ref byte[] ByteArr , string FileName,ref int CurrentRecord, ref int EndOfFile)
    {
        byte[] Byte = new byte[PageSize * PageNumber];
        for(int a = 0; a < Byte.Length; a++)
        {
            Byte[a] = 0xFF;
        }
        long MaxPoint = (PageNumber * PageSize);
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
        int Offset = 0;
        int BytePointer = 0;
        int RecordSize = 0;
        int CheckSum = 0;
        int CheckSumT = 0;
        int CheckSumM = 0;
        CurrentRecord = 1;
        int LastBytePoint = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; )
        {
            if (file[i] != ':') return 1;

            i++;
            RecordSize = AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 16;
            i++;
            RecordSize += AsciiToByte(file[i]);
            i++;
            if (RecordSize > 256) return 2;
            CheckSum = RecordSize;

            Offset =  AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 4096;
            CheckSum += AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 16;
            i++;
            Offset += AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 256;
            CheckSum += AsciiToByte(file[i]);
            i++;
            Offset += AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 16;
            CheckSum += AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 16;
            i++;
            Offset += AsciiToByte(file[i]);
            CheckSum += AsciiToByte(file[i]);
            i++;
            if ((Offset + RecordSize) >= MaxPoint) return 3;
            else BytePointer = Offset;
            if((Offset + RecordSize - 1) > LastBytePoint) LastBytePoint = Offset + RecordSize -1;

            if (file[i] != '0') return 4;
            i++;
            if (file[i] == '1')
            {
                if (RecordSize != 0) return 9;
                i++;
                if (file[i] != 'F') return 5;
                i++;
                if (file[i] != 'F') return 5;
                i++;
                if (file[i] != 13) return 7;
                i++;
                if (file[i] != 10) return 8;
                EndOfFile = LastBytePoint;
                break;
            }
            else if (file[i] != '0') return 4;
            i++;
            for(int j=0; j<RecordSize; j++)
            {
                Byte[BytePointer] = (byte)(AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 16);
                i++;
                Byte[BytePointer] += (byte)(AsciiToByte(file[i]));
                CheckSum += Byte[BytePointer];
                BytePointer++;
                i++;
            }
            CheckSumM = (AsciiToByte(file[i]) * 16);
            i++;
            CheckSumM += AsciiToByte(file[i]);
            i++;
            CheckSumT = ((~CheckSum) & 0xFF) + 1;
            if (CheckSumM != CheckSumT) return 6;


            if (file[i] != 13) return 7;
            i++;
            if (file[i] != 10) return 8;
            i++;

            CurrentRecord++;

        }
        ByteArr = Byte;
        return 0;
    }
```

its that for now and works fine . thanks everyone